# Dynamic triggers with table_name in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, trigger

I want make a dynamic trigger with PostgreSQL/PostGIS like this. I try that triggers make more generic for use with many tables with the same pattern. When i use direct table's name in code, that's works but

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asst.inter_geom_insee() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$body$
    DECLARE
        tbl text := quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA) || '.' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME);
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' or TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
            UPDATE '|| tbl ||' SET insee = c.insee_com FROM cadastre.COMMUNE AS c WHERE st_within('|| tbl ||'.geom, c.geom);
        END IF;
    RETURN NEW; 
    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I try in my code

```
EXECUTE 'UPDATE '|| tbl ||' SET insee = c.insee_com FROM cadastre.COMMUNE AS c WHERE st_within('|| tbl ||'.geom, c.geom)' USING NEW;
```

but nothing, just one answer from dbeaver :

> ERROR: asst.inter_geom_insee() is not a procedure

I see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519044/how-to-dynamically-use-tg-table-name-in-postgresql-8-2
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997337/inserting-new-from-a-generic-trigger-using-execute-in-pl-pgsql
But I fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a dynamic query here because you are updating the same record that is being inserted/updated. You can directly modify the `NEW` object:

```sql
NEW.insee := (SELECT c.insee_com FROM cadastre.COMMUNE AS c WHERE st_within(NEW.geom, c.geom));
```

PS: thought it is slightly different from the OP, as the original query would have updated the entire table each time...

Comment: so simple, big thank !